# JavaScript hexadecimal to ascii character replace by regex

Tags: javascript

I want to translate hexadecimal results into ASCII character

I try this but I can't do it:

```
output.content = decodeResults[0].content.replace("%3C0xc5%3E%3C0x9f%3C%3E", "asd");
```

My char hex code is <0xc5><0x9f>

[image]

default code

```
    // Default script for data formatting
function onResult (decodeResults, readerProperties, output)
{
    if (decodeResults[0].decoded)
    {
        output.content = decodeResults[0].content;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean you want to unescape, try `unescape`, `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: It came from barcode reader.  I want to write a script to barcode reader.

Answer (score 0):

I found it

```
function onResult (decodeResults, readerProperties, output)
{
    if(decodeResults.toString)
    {
      var OkunanBarkod = decodeResults[0].content;

            while(OkunanBarkod.match('\xc5') && OkunanBarkod.match('\x9f') && (OkunanBarkod.indexOf('\xc5') == (OkunanBarkod.indexOf('\x9f')-1)))
            {       
                OkunanBarkod = OkunanBarkod.replace('\xc5', 's');

                OkunanBarkod = OkunanBarkod.replace('\x9f', '');            
            }

            while(OkunanBarkod.match('\xc3') && OkunanBarkod.match('\xb6') && (OkunanBarkod.indexOf('\xc3') == (OkunanBarkod.indexOf('\xb6') - 1)))
            {       
                OkunanBarkod = OkunanBarkod.replace('\xc3', 'o');

                OkunanBarkod = OkunanBarkod.replace('\xb6', '');            
            }



            output.content = OkunanBarkod;

    }
    else{
        output.content = "no";
    }
```

But i can't find a solution for show it as "ş" character.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the format of your decodeResults[0].content ? Your replace statement suggests a URL-encoded string.
JavaScript replace is not specifically concerned with this type of encoding, it handles input as just a series of characters.

For this input: '<0xc5><0x9f>' I'd suggest escaping the < and > characters:

```
    .replace('\<0xc5\>\<0x9f\>', 'asd')
```

Check it out at the JSFiddle I created: [JSFiddle for replace](https://jsfiddle.net/9hp8db7a/)